# Cassandra nodes are not equal

Tags: cassandra

We have two nodes. Node1 was down for a long time. During this time Node2 raised 1 TB capacity when Node1 has 100 GB.

We tried to repair Node1 with nodetool repair but nothing changed. After that we started nodetool repair in Node2, it took 5 days to compaction but nothing changed either.

Actual status here:

```
Datacenter: dc1
===============
Status=Up/Down

|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID    Rack

UN  172.x.y.z     149.46 GB  256          100.0%            xxx  rack1
UN  172.x.y.k     1.04 TB    256          100.0%            xyz  rack1
```

Nodes are in AWS. What should we do?

Comment: What replication factor are you using?

Comment: @ChristopheSchmitz cqlsh:5.0.1 cassandra: 3.0.9 CQL Spec: 3.4.0, Replication factor = 2

Comment: Are you doing any delete queries? Are you using TTL?

Comment: @ChristopheSchmitz We have never done delete queries yet and we are not using TTL. We only use store data and do some backward processing jobs.

Answer (score 1):

We had a solution but don't know how it happened. Here what we did:

- Took snapshot of both servers in case of data loss over AWS
- We detached Volume where data is stored. (for instance 172.x.y.k)
- We formatted instance and loaded Cassandra with new version. Then we
  attached Volume where data is stored.
- Finally we started `nodetool repair --full` in terminal and it took 4
  days.

Now our nodes are equal.